# How do I define a variable in a RSpec feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im learning Rails 4 and and trying to write some tests using Rspec and capybara. Im writing a feature test for my users and I'm trying to test a user signing in.

```
feature "User" do
        scenario "A user signs in" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
            visit signin_path

            fill_in "Username", with: user.username
            fill_in "Password", with: "123456"
            click_button "Log in"

            expect(page).to have_content(user.username)
        end
end
```

Its telling me that let is an undefined method. and I'm sure that the problem is that it is in a feature/scenario test. How do I define the user in this kind of test?

Also, in a describe/it request test like this

```
describe "Something" do
    it "should do something" do
        expect(page).to have_content{"...")
    end
end
```

I can shorten it like this

```
describe "Something" do
    subject { page }
    it { should have_content("...") }
end
```

Is there a way to shorten the `expect(page).....` in a scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let` is used for lazy-initialization of "variables" as needed across multiple tests; initializing it in a test is nonsensical. Either move the let outside of the `scenario` block, or just use standard variable assignment, like `user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was basing my use of "let(:user)" off of the Hartl Rails tutorial, and he explains the use of request tests using `let(:variable)` for multiple tests. Is there a solution for the second part of my question?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; `it` is analogous to `scenario`, but acceptance tests are a different beast from unit/functional tests, in that they typically test progression through a series of states, which wouldn't make sense with the more terse format. I'm sure it's possible somehow, but I've never seen it done.